# Android Query MediaStore using IN clause

Tags: android, media

I'm trying to pull all the tracks for items i've stored in a "playlist", I have a set of `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID` values and I'm trying to build a query using the IN clause, the example below doesn't work...

```
        String[] projection = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID};

        String whereString = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " IN (?)";

        String[] selectionArgs = {"626,625"};
```

But, if I change the `selecionArgs` to

```
        String[] selectionArgs = {"626"};
```

It does work

Should the IN clause work or am I going to have to build up a lot of `OR` statements (which I obviously don't want to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else tried to do this the IN statement needs a matching number of '?', i.e. you can't have a single parameter that has a list of values, so this works...

```
    String[] projection = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID};

    String whereString = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " IN (?,?)";

    String[] selectionArgs = {"626","625"};
```

Comment: What if you don't know the size of array (selectionArgs)?

Comment: @DivyangM - you could build the "(?,?)" part of the query string dynamically based on the number of elements in the arry

Comment: That's what I did eventually. But I thought maybe there's better way to do it. Anyway Thanks for the reply.